# Find if two nodes are cousin nodes or sibling nodes in Binary Tree in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, data-structures, binary-tree

I know the idea is to first do **level order traversal** on the tree.

If the nodes are found on the same level and their parents do not match they are **cousins**.

And if matches they are **siblings**.

I can do level order traversal by

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.levelOrderTraversal = function() {
    var q = [];
    var results = [];
    var _root = this.root;
    if(_root) {
        q.push(_root);
        while(q.length > 0) {
            var temp = q.shift();
            results.push(temp.value);
            if(temp.left) {
                q.push(temp.left);
            }
            if(temp.right) {
                q.push(temp.right);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }else {
        return null;
    }

}
```

But now how do I keep track of parents so that I can find given nodes are siblings or cousins?

For example,

if my level order traversal gives me

[3, 2, 4, 1, 5]

**3 being root, 2 and 4 are siblings or parent 3.**

**1 is a left child of parent 2.**

**5 is a right child of parent 4.**

**so, 1 and 5 are cousin nodes while 2 and 4 are sibling nodes.**

Comment: do you have some data to test?

Comment: @NinaScholz Just updated the question.

Comment: please add the tree object and the result, you like as data structure.

Comment: do you still want to take the same level traversal or another, like depth first?

Comment: @NinaScholz anything is fine I am just not sure which way to follow. I read somewhere level order can also be implemented, but anyway should be fine.

Comment: and how do you wnat to get the result,. i mean do you take a node and check the relation?

Comment: @NinaScholz would ideally pass two nodes and check if they are cousins or siblings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the path to the wanted nodes and check the same length of the pathes and the last or the element before the last for getting the relation.

```js
function getPath(node, value, path = []) {
    if (!node) {
        return;
    }
    if (node.value === value) {
        return path;
    }
    return getPath(node.left, value, path.concat(node.value))
        || getPath(node.right, value, path.concat(node.value));
}

function findRelation(root, a, b) {
    var pathA = getPath(root, a),
        pathB = getPath(root, b);

    if (pathA.length !== pathB.length) {
        return;
    }
    if (pathA.length && pathA[pathA.length - 1] === pathB[pathB.length - 1]) {
        return 'siblings';
    }

    if (pathA.length > 1 && pathA[pathA.length - 2] === pathB[pathB.length - 2]) {
        return 'cousins';
    }
}

var tree = { value: 3, left: { value: 2, left: { value: 1 } }, right: { value: 4, right: { value: 5 } } };

console.log(findRelation(tree, 2, 4));
console.log(findRelation(tree, 1, 5));
```

Comment: Awesome. You are a true legend :) Such a different way of thinking :) Could you suggest me some things as to how to approach a problem in a different way altogether.

Comment: "*Could you suggest me some things as to how to approach a problem in a different way altogether.*" ad hoc? what looks shorter to write. but seriously, you need how some things work, like trees, iteration and recursion. and if not known somthing, just try and try more times. that is the beauty about software/programming, you could try anything without harm.